# Prune remote branches after fetch refspec changes

Tags: git

I've changed fetch refspec to hide remote branches, currently I have only `master`:

```
$ git config remote.origin.fetch
+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

But all other branches are still here, `git branch -r` shows them. How to prune them? `git remote prune origin` and `git fetch --prune origin` do nothing.

git v1.8.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Git will not prune remote branches that do not match the configured fetch refspec, but only those that truly no longer exist. So once you change the refspec, Git simply ignores the existing remote branches completely.

I’m afraid you have to delete the remote branches manually then:

```
git branch -d -r origin/other-branch
```

---

The [documentation for `fetch --prune`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) actually explains this behavior in a bit in regards to tags (emphasis mine):

> After fetching, remove any remote-tracking references that no longer exist on the remote. Tags are not subject to pruning if they are fetched only because of the default tag auto-following or due to a --tags option. **However, if tags are fetched due to an explicit refspec** (either on the command line or in the remote configuration, for example if the remote was cloned with the --mirror option)**, then they are also subject to pruning**.

So tags are only pruned if they are included in the refspec; this means that `fetch --prune` will probably only prune references it would access with the refspec. So if you exclude branches from the refspec, those branches are no longer subject to pruning.

---

If you want to get rid of *a lot* of remote branches, you could always go the hacky way and modify the contents of the `.git` directory. There are two places where the branches are stored:

1. As explicit reference files in `.git/refs/remotes/origin`: So you could just remove the files for the remote branches you no longer want there.
2. As packed references in `.git/packed-refs`: There you need to remove the lines that look like this: `<commit-hash> refs/remotes/origin/<branch>`.

Alternatively, you could also remove the remote completely using `git remote remove origin`. Of course that will also remove the tracking information of your local branches. *However*, you can back up that information pretty easily by making a copy of the `.git/config` file. The tracking information is only stored there in a format like this:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

So if you back up that file, then remove the remote, and then restore the `.git/config`, then the remote should be back again (including your custom refspec) and a subsequent `git fetch` should only fetch those branches that are included in your custom refspec. And previously existing mappings to your local branches are restored as well.

Comment: I have about hundred of them... It would be difficult to delete one by one. I could delete all branches with one command and re-fetch, but I afraid it will destroy local branch tracking information...

Comment: @kan You can always manually mess with the `.git` folder in that case. I’ve added instructions to my answer about that. It should work fine that way, but you might want to make backups just in case.

Comment: Ok, I've done it with `git for-each-ref --format "%(refname)" refs/remotes/origin | xargs git update-ref -d` and then `git fetch`. Works ok, and I believe it's safer than hacking `.git`